# Android Gingerbread: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, looper

I have a code like this:

```
final Context context = this;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        new CheckMessageTask(context).execute(); //ERROR
    }
}, 2500, 10 * 60 * 1000); //Every 10 Minutes
```

The Timer should execute CheckMessageTask every 10 minutes.
The problem is that this error appears:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at -package-CheckMessageService$1.run(CheckMessageService.java:138)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
    ... 2 more
```

CheckMessageTask extends Asynctask and doesn't run UI code, so that is not the reason.
The code works fine on Android Jelly Bean 4.1.2, but not on Android Gingerbread.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13267931/1468093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timer task runs on a different thread. You should load asynctask on the main ui thread

Check the link below under the topic Threading Rules

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The `AsyncTask` class must be loaded on the `UI thread`. This is done automatically as of `JELLY_BEAN`.

So in Jelly bean it works fine.

Comment: first of all why do you need a asynctask since service runs in the background?

Comment: because it is connecting to the internet, doesnt that throw an exception if it doesnt uses an asynctask?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot execute Asynctask from not a UI thread which is a case when using a Timer

Comment: because in 4.1.2 this done automatically. The `AsyncTask` class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is `done automatically` as of `JELLY_BEAN`.

Comment: have no idea, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html section "Threading rules"

Comment: @Trojaner can you explain why you want a timer? i think you have to rethink your appraoxh

Comment: The code is executed by a service, so there is no UI Thread. @Raghunandan how should i do it?

Comment: @Trojaner i suggest you rethink your design. service runs in background. in service you have a timer and you load asynctask inside the timer. you have to change your approach. do you need parallel execution?